# Insert batch inserting limited values in the database and not inserting the data completely, using PHP and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I would like to insert multiple records in the database and tried using insert batch, unfortunately it inserts 2 values but did not insert the complete set of data.

Here is my view, I made my input tags as an array

```
  <?php foreach($subjects as $subject): ?>
       <input type="hidden" name="studentID[]" value="<?php echo $subject['studentID']; ?>" />
       <input type="hidden" name="school[]" value="<?php echo $subject['school']; ?>" />
       <input type="hidden" name="major[]" value="<?php echo $subject['major']; ?>" />
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

In my controller, I am just calling the model and redirecting the page once I hit the form

```
 public function insertSubjects()
    {   
        $data['subjects'] = $this->gradeaction_model->insertGrades();

        redirect('/');        

    }
```

In the model, first I identified all the input tags with array and create an array called `$value` and made a for loop. Afterwards, I tried to insert it using the insert batch. The result is that it added only 2 values but did not add all complete data. How can I possibly add the complete set of data that I would like to insert?

```
   public function insertGrades(){

        $studentID = $this->input->post('studentID[]');
        $school = $this->input->post('school[]');
        $major = $this->input->post('major[]');

        $value = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($studentID); $i++) {
            $value[$i] = array(
                'studentID' => $studentID[$i],
                'school' => $school[$i],
                'major' => $major[$i],
             );
     }
        $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_tt_academicsubinfo_college', $value);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code on view:

```
 <?php foreach($subjects as $subject): ?>
         <input type="hidden" name="studentID[]" value="<?php echo $subject['studentID']; ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="school[]" value="<?php echo $subject['school']; ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="major[]" value="<?php echo $subject['major']; ?>" />
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The code on model:

```
public function insertGrades(){

        $studentID = $this->input->post('studentID');
        $school = $this->input->post('school');
        $major = $this->input->post('major');

        $value = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($studentID); $i++) {
           $value[$i] = array(
               'studentID' => $studentID[$i],
               'school' => $school[$i],
               'major' => $major[$i],
            );
     }
        $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_tt_academicsubinfo_college', $value);
   }
```

Comment: It says that in the model `Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable` on this loop `for($i = 0; $i < count($studentID); $i++) {` is there any way to fix this ,sir?

Comment: additionally I have addeld `(array($studentID))` on the for loop to remove the error count, but the next error is that `Message: Undefined offset: 0` on the line of the array values.

Comment: please share the value of `$studentID` using `var_dump()` to figure what it is

Comment: based on what you have given, it is `NULL`

Comment: I found my mistake, there is no need to add the `$i` in the HTML input ,I will edit my answer

Comment: okay sir, thank you for this response. will wait for the update.

Comment: the only edit you need on your code is to remove the `[]` from the input name `$this->input->post('studentID');`

Comment: I var_dump the studentID again, saying it is null. And now I tried to insert the data but `Column 'studentID' cannot be null` was shown.

Comment: did you return the Html code as it was?

Comment: yes, just like what you have edited and suggested earlier to remove the `[]` from the input name

Comment: So check your data in `$subjects`

Comment: if I var dump the `$subjects` then I have the set of data . But if I var dump for example the studentID or any variables it gives me `null`

Comment: let's reorganize the thoughts,
*Don't change your HTML code*
*Just remove the `[]` from the input name in the model*
and the code will work fine

Comment: I did not, `[]` from the model were not included.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working yet. I have just followed what you have said and done even in your answer codes. I am puzzled about this.

Comment: There is another way to do this, replace `$this->input->post('studentID')` with `$_POST['studentID']` and the same for other inputs, Try it.